# What's the purpose of Strobe frequency adjustment in Torch?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-ace, camera-flash

I have the Torch app by default in Cyanogenmod.

I was wondering what's the purpose of Strobe frequency adjustment?

I tried to play around with it and I couldn't tell what difference does it make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Strobe light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strobe_light) is a kind of light which goes on and off a given number of times. The inverse of the number of times it goes on and off in a second is called its frequency. Strobe lights are used to see rotating objects to give an illumination that the rotating object is stationary.

By adjusting the strobe frequency the speed of the rotating object is matched to get the desired illusion effect.

There are many uses of strobe light from testing and instrumentation to dancing!

Comment: Well I know what a strobe light is, thing is, I adjusted it so many times it doesn't make a difference. My LED light is just steady. Does it mean my device doesn't support it?

Comment: I am sorry, it was not apparent for me. AFAIK, camera's LED flash are super responsive as they burst flash. Probably our eyes can't distinguish the strobe unless the frequency is distinctively low. If you say that the LED is steady by looking at it, then you can test it against a rotating object or test again with very low frequency.

Comment: Ok I tried again after reboot. It works now.